# Drawing a line that approaches a circle normally

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a `node` (using TikZ and the shapes library)

```
\node (c0) [circle, draw] at (0,0) {foo};
```

and a coordinate

```
\coordinate (c1) at (4,2);
```

How can I draw a line from `c1` to `c0.north west` such that the line first proceeds horizontally along the `y` coordinate of `c1` (here 2), and then turn towards `c0` at the appropriate point, so that it is normal to the circle when it hits `c0.north west`? Both segments are straight lines, with the bend being either sharp/rounded corners (it doesn't matter). Here's a simple sketch of the above:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose an angle on the border of the node (no need for coordinates since their center is also the border coordinate) and use that to perform a simple calculation. Let's say we take 30 (`north west` is 135, second picture below and then 10) then we have

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (c0) [circle, draw] at (0,0) {foo};
\coordinate (c1) at (4,2);

\draw let \p1=($(c1)-(c0.30)$),\n1={\y1/sin(30)} in (c0.30)--++(30:\n1) -- (c1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can further furnish this simple idea with a style, make angle a variable etc. Obviously you we want our angle to be in [0+ε,π-ε] for some small ε tolerance otherwise see you at infinity (which for me is the textwidth).

Comment: `\p1` and `\y1` intermixed?

Comment: @Toscho By intermixed you mean they need to be swapped? `\p1` is the coordinate, `\y1` is the vertical component of `\p1`

Comment: Please ignore my previous, unqualified comment. I learned something new about tikz.

Comment: @Toscho Haha no problem at all.